# Getting the right active record call with joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

The current issue I'm running into is where as I increased the number of posts being created from my users, there is a long pause to access the correct information required for my newsfeed.

Was hoping someone can either help me or point me in the right direction to optimize my current method which is

```
def newsfeed
 @friends ||= self.in_friends.where("friends.status = 
'Accepted'").includes(:posts) + self.out_friends.where("friends.status = 'Accepted'").includes(:posts)
 @something = self.profile_posts.where("owner_id = ?", self.id)

 @posts = []

 @friends.each { |friend| @posts += friend.posts }
 @newsfeed = @posts + @something

 @newsfeed.sort! { |a, b|  b.created_at <=> a.created_at }

end
```

This isn't a very clean query and was hoping to get better advice in being able to learn/implement a faster one.

Further information are the tables being associated are

```
  create_table "friends", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "friender_id", null: false
    t.string "status", default: "Pending", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "friendee_id"
    t.index ["friendee_id"], name: "index_friends_on_friendee_id"
    t.index ["friender_id"], name: "index_friends_on_friender_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "owner_id", null: false
    t.string "text", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "profile_id"
    t.index ["owner_id"], name: "index_posts_on_owner_id"
  end
```

What I have been trying to implement are all posts posted by a user friends plus the post the current user posted on their profile page. Something along the line of (friend2 and posts2 are aliases)

```
select * from posts 
join friend 
join friend2
join posts2
where friend.friender_id = self.id and status = 'Accepted'
where friend2.friendee_id = self.id and status = 'Accepted'
where posts2 profile_id = self.id and owner_id = self.id
```

Thank you to all who help me in regards to this issue I'm having. Also those who help me better improve in my understanding of 'SQL'/'ActiveRecord'.

Comment: Are friend and friend2 different tables, or aliases of the same table? Likewise for posts and posts2.

Comment: @GregViers Thanks for the reply. They are aliases (sorry for not mentioning that) since a current user can be a friender_id or a friendee_id depending if they were added by someone else or they added the person them self. As for post2 I was thinking since I wanted the current user posts I would need an extra table where it'll grab the current user posts from their profile.

Comment: If they are aliases, you should use AS in your JOIN clause.. write JOIN friend AS friend1 JOIN friend as Friend2 etc.

Comment: @GregViers I'm sorry if I'm still a bit confused since I'm very weak currently when it comes to using SQL/ActiveRecord. When using for example JOIN friend AS friend1 we don't need to associate it with an id to join them? like for example where it'll be select * from movies join actors as actors2 = movies_actor.id = actor.id ?

Comment: Here are some examples to get more familiar with it: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/alias